# How to do netcat with gawk networking?

Tags: sockets, awk, ssh, netcat

I'm on machine that have very old netcat version which don't support HTTP proxy option (`-X`). And i need to do netcat through HTTP proxy on this machine (to proxyfy ssh with proxy command).

I've tryed to send `CONNECT <host>:<port>` with the old netcat before passing the stdin/out to ssh but without success.

I've found that gawk as networking support according [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/gawkinet.html) and I've tried to make netcat working with it but without success.

How to send `CONNECT` command first, read the response of the proxy and go in read/write stdin/stdout in two way loop after?